# python numpy - unable to compare 2 arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the 2 arrays as follows:

```
x = array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-01'], dtype=object)
z = array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-02', '2019-03-01'], dtype=object)
```

I'm trying to use np.where to determine on which index the 2 matrixes are aligned.

I'm doing
`i = np.where (z == x)` but it doesn't work, I get an empty array as a result. It looks like it's comparing the whole array is equal to the other whole array whereas I'm looking for the matching values and would like to get matching results between the 2. How should I do it ?

Thanks

Regards

edit: expected outcome is yes [True, False, False]

Comment: What's the exact expected output?

Comment: I assume the expected output would be either `[True, False, False]` or just `[1]` ?

Comment: yes [True, False, False]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` result is only as good as the boolean it searches.  If the argument does not have any True values, `where` returns empty:

```
In [308]: x = np.array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-01'], dtype=object) 
     ...: z = np.array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-02', '2019-03-01'], dtype=object)                             
In [309]: x==z                                                                                               
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[309]: False
```

If you aren't concerned about order:

```
In [311]: np.isin(z,x)                                                                                       
Out[311]: array([ True, False,  True])
```

or trimming `z`:

```
In [312]: x==z[:2]                                                                                           
Out[312]: array([ True, False])
```

to extend `x` you could first use `np.pad`, or use `itertools.zip_longest`

```
In [353]: list(itertools.zip_longest(x,z))                                                                   
Out[353]: 
[('2019-02-28', '2019-02-28'),
 ('2019-03-01', '2019-03-02'),
 (None, '2019-03-01')]
In [354]: [i==j for i,j in itertools.zip_longest(x,z)]                                                       
Out[354]: [True, False, False]
```

`zip_longest` accepts other fill values if that makes the comparison better.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need:

```
print([i for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x, z)) if x == y])
```

Answer (score 1):

As the two arrays have different sizes compare over the minimum of the two sizes.

**Edit:**
I just reread the question and comments.

```
result= np.zeros( max(x.size, z.size), dtype=bool) # result size of the biggest array.
size = min(x.size, z.size)
result[:size] = z[:size] == x[:size] # Comparison at smallest size.

result
# array([ True, False, False])
```

This gives the boolean mask the comment asks for.

**Original answer**

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-01'], dtype=object)
z = np.array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-02', '2019-03-01'], dtype=object)

size = min(x.size, z.size)    
np.where(z[:size]==x[:size])  # Select the common range
# (array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

On my machine this is slower than the list comprehension from @U10-Forward for dtype=object but faster if numpy selects the dtype, 'Unicode 10'.

```
x = np.array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-01'])
z = np.array(['2019-02-28', '2019-03-02', '2019-03-01'])
```